# Eclipse Juno Loading descriptor error

Tags: eclipse, descriptor

I just updated my Eclipse from Galileo to Juno. I created a new workspace and imported a Java Spring MVC based project. When I open it, it begins 'Loading descriptor' and then an error message pops up: An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for mta_pfm.". If I open it using Galileo, there is no error. I tried to disable the validation of XML file in Juno, but it does not work. I have no idea how to fix it now. Please help. Thanks

```
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.IllegalValueException: Value '
    Container
  ' is not legal. (platform:/resource/mta_pfm/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml, 138, 14)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.getResource(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.JEE5ModelProvider.getModelResource(JEE5ModelProvider.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.Web25ModelProvider.getModelObject(Web25ModelProvider.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.JEE5ModelProvider.getModelObject(JEE5ModelProvider.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.loadProviders(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.access$2(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider$LoadModelsWorkspaceRunnable.run(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.loadModel(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.getMergedModel(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.model.internal.common.AbstractMergedModelProvider.getModelObject(AbstractMergedModelProvider.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25ContentProvider.getNewContentProviderInstance(Web25ContentProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.LoadingJeeDDJob.run(LoadingJeeDDJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.IllegalValueException: Value '
    Container
  ' is not legal. (platform:/resource/mta_pfm/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml, 138, 14)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setFeatureValue(XMLHandler.java:2657)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setFeatureValue(XMLHandler.java:2642)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.endElement(XMLHandler.java:1564)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1505)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1284)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value '
    Container
  ' is not a valid enumerator of 'ResAuthType'
    at org.eclipse.jst.javaee.core.internal.impl.JavaeeFactoryImpl.createResAuthTypeFromString(JavaeeFactoryImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jst.javaee.core.internal.impl.JavaeeFactoryImpl.createFromString(JavaeeFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHelperImpl.createFromString(XMLHelperImpl.java:1615)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHelperImpl.setValue(XMLHelperImpl.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setFeatureValue(XMLHandler.java:2652)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your projects file may be incompatible with Juno (Juno in it's first release is not very stable, I recommend downloading the official update patches or even better - moving to Kepler which feels more solid).

Anyway, Eclipse can take some runtime arguments as described here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

Edit your Juno eclipse.exe shortcut and run "'...\eclipse.exe' -clean" to refresh your project files.

Remember to remove the argument once it's fixed as you have no need to clean the project files every time you start eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start eclipse in clean mode from the command line

```
eclipse -clean
```