# An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for ... java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

When ever I refresh my Dynamic Web Project (or save a file), it gives met his error. It actually usually displays the same error three times.

The other answers I've looked at here suggest it only happens when the person creates a new project. This has started happening just recently.

Looking at the workspace/.metadata/.log shows me a range of errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 4 0 2015-05-15 15:20:16.141
!MESSAGE No IModelProvider exists for project P/MyWebProject of version: Dynamic Web Module 2.5
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException: No IModelProvider exists for project P/MyWebProject of version: Dynamic Web Module 2.5
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.JEE5ContentProvider.getCachedModelProvider(JEE5ContentProvider.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25ContentProvider.getNewContentProviderInstance(Web25ContentProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.LoadingJeeDDJob.run(LoadingJeeDDJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-05-15 15:20:16.141
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for MyWebProject.".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.JEE5ContentProvider.getCachedModelProvider(JEE5ContentProvider.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25ContentProvider.getNewContentProviderInstance(Web25ContentProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.LoadingJeeDDJob.run(LoadingJeeDDJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: try deleting .classpath and . project  in the project folder and then create a new project pointing to the project folder

Comment: This is a recurrent bug, you can view a possible solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844989/eclipse-juno-loading-descriptor-error

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Deleting the project and rechecking it out solved this problem.

Answer (score 5):

This problem had occurred in many forms, e.g.
[Error when creating a new Vaadin project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476138/error-when-creating-a-new-vaadin-project-in-eclipse)

Solution: install these:

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- JST Server Adapters
- JST Server Adapters Extensions

(In my case,  Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools  was missing.)

Comment: This advice is vetted for creating a web service per many web-provided examples using Eclipse 2022-03 (4.232.0), java 15.0.1; Apache Tomcat 9.0.55.  Run the server from Eclipse. 5 yrs later, and your advice is still relevant!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your web.xml will be in error. Check for any servlet mapping for an invalid class and remove the mapping and clean your project .

Comment: it worked for me. I removed the entire listener code which i did not need anyway. 
<listener>
 <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
Then clean maven. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe in error. Or maybe you really need those elements - have to check.  :)